# log4j2 not working for JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, logging, classpath, log4j2

I am trying to use `log4j2` with dynamic log directory location. I wrote code for this as:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Constants.DATE_FORMAT);
Date date = new Date();

String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/" + Constants.OUTPUT_FOLDER_NAME + "/" + dateFormat.format(date);
System.setProperty("logDir", currentDir);
final LoggerContext ctx = (LoggerContext)LogManager.getContext(false);
ctx.reconfigure();
```

The log4j2.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="trace">
    <Appenders>
        <File name="file" fileName="${sys:logDir}/log.log">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{ISO8601} [%t] %C %M - %p: %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>

        <File name="report" fileName="${sys:logDir}/report.txt">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </File>

        <Console name="console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout>
                <Pattern>%d{ISO8601} - %p: %m%n</Pattern>
            </PatternLayout>
        </Console>
    </Appenders>

    <Loggers>

        <Logger name="Report" level="info" additivity="false">
            <AppenderRef ref="report" level="INFO"/>
        </Logger>

        <Root level="info">
            <AppenderRef ref="file" level="INFO" />
            <AppenderRef ref="console" level="INFO" />
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

The files are generated fine when I run this in Eclipse, but when I run the main class of my program using a JAR file containing the compiled main class on the classpath as:

```
java -cp CLASSPATH -Dlog4j.configuration=file:XMLFILE ClassName args
```

it only prints the 'error' messages to the console. The directory structure and the files are also not created. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obviously the Logger cannot find your configuration. Is it exported within the JAR (look with an archive explorer)? Try find out why it isn't where it has to be and update your program.

Comment: thank you ! I wasn't including the directory of the XML file in the classpath.

Answer (score 0):

The location must be specified with `-Dlog4j.configurationFile`, not `-Dlog4j.configuration`.

See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/faq.html#config_location

Comment: In my experience, `-Dlog4j.configuration` works too with a URL, like `file:path/to/file.xml`. I went with `-Dlog4j.configurationFile` too in the end though :)

Comment: -Dlog4j.configuration only works in log4j-1.x, not in log4j2. But you can use a URL both in log4j-1.x and log4j2.